# Return to previous scroll position in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

i have a RecyclerView which displays some data. I also have a floating action button which takes the user to a new Activity. But when the user goes back to the previous Activity (containing the RecyclerView), the user is taken to the top of the list.
How can I prevent that and return the user to where they were before clicking on the floating action button?

Comment: you can save the scroll position while going forward, & on return set that saved scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a late response.  Here is what you can do:

1) Get your current position from your layout manager like so:

```
int mPosition =  mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

2) Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
and save your visible position like so:

```
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(KEY_SCROLL_POS, mPosition);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

3) Restore your position upon activity reentry:
  in `onCreate()` do the following:

```
mPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_SCROLL_POS);
```

Hope that helps.